# Flutter animation show movement of list item

Tags: flutter-animation

I have 2 list scroll horizontal.
When I click in the item of above list, this item will move to below list.
I want to have animation which will show the movement progress of this item.
Help me!!!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

inview_notifier_list: https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list

effect:
flutter_shimmer: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_shimmer

Comment: Thank you for helping. But I want to item in above list which will fly to below list.

Comment: And having an animation to show this progress.

Comment: Tìm trong này xem có không ông: https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter

Comment: Muốn có cái animation nó bay từ list trên xuống list ở dưới mà căng quá. Nó bay trong cùng 1 list thì còn dễ chứ 2 list khác nhau xong move sang nhau chưa biết nên làm thế nào